# Removing Object in NSMutable Array using NSMutable Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to remove object in Mutable array using mutable dictionary, How?

My code :

```
Employees *Emp7 = [[Employees alloc] init];
Emp7.Number = 7;
Emp7.Name = @"Safa'";
[EmployeesArray addObject:Emp1];
[Dictionary setValue:Emp1 forKey:Emp1.Name];
```

in the Deleting button (IBAction)

```
Employees *objEmp2 = [Dic1 objectForKey:objEmp1.Name ];
[Dic1 removeObjectForKey:@"Safa'"];
```

Comment: What actually you want to do?

Comment: i create NSMutableArray, which contain objects, each object has "name","Number"...etc, then i create NSMutable Dictionary, which i add all objects of MutableArray to MutableDictionary ...
then i want delete the object in the mutableArray by query object.name or obj.number , How ?

Comment: Please put the code in your question (not in a comment) and use the code formatting.

Comment: Please. edit. your question. Not. a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please be a little more clear with your question, is this what you are looking for ?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
[array removeObject:[dict objectForKey:someKey]];
```

where 'values' and 'keys' are both arrays and 'somekey' is an object in the 'keys' array.
Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: i want to remove object by his " name " in the mutable array using NSDictionary < How ?

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED CODE : 100 % WORKS**

```
NSMutableArray *EmployeesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *EmployeesArrayToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Employees *Emp7 = [[Employees alloc] init];
Emp7.number = @"7"; Emp7.Name = @"Safa'"; 
[EmployeesArray addObject:Emp7];

Employees *Emp3 = [[Employees alloc] init];
Emp3.number = @"7"; Emp3.Name = @"AppleVijay@facebook.com"; 
[EmployeesArray addObject:Emp3];

Employees *EmployeToDelete = [[Employees alloc] init];
EmployeToDelete.number = @"7"; 
EmployeToDelete.Name = @"Safa'"; 

NSLog(@"before delete : %@",EmployeesArray);

for (Employees *eachEmployee in EmployeesArray) {
    if ([eachEmployee.Name isEqual:EmployeToDelete.Name] && [eachEmployee.number isEqual: EmployeToDelete.number]) {
        [EmployeesArrayToDelete addObject:eachEmployee];
    }
}

if ([EmployeesArrayToDelete count]>0) {
    [EmployeesArray removeObjectsInArray:EmployeesArrayToDelete];
}

NSLog(@" After delete Employeesarray : %@",EmployeesArray);
```